# No credentials: Error in AWS AMPLIFY react-native expo App

Tags: react-native, graphql, expo, aws-amplify, spotify

I create Spotify clone App with help of AWS Amplify.
Can't call GraphQLAPI, when call that api it return this
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bICL3.png)
But That App is working Fine,
[GraphQLAPI Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCHbJ.png)

Here is the Schema File
**Schema.graphql**

```js
type AlbumCategory @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  albums: [Album] @connection(keyName: "byAlbumCategory", fields: ["id"])
}

type Album @model @key(name: "byAlbumCategory", fields: ["albumCategoryId"]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  by: String!
  numberOfLikes: Int!
  imageUri: String!
  artistsHeadline: String!

  songs: [Song] @connection(keyName: "byAlbum", fields: ["id"])

  albumCategoryId: ID!
  albumCategory: AlbumCategory @connection(fields: ["albumCategoryId"])
}

type Song @model @key(name: "byAlbum", fields: ["albumId"]) {
  id: ID!
  imageUri: String!
  uri: String!
  title: String!
  artist: String!

  albumId: ID!
  album: Album @connection(fields: ["albumId"])
}
```

Here is the myExecutabal Query...
**Query:**

```js
    export const listAlbumCategorys = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListAlbumCategorys(
    $filter: ModelAlbumCategoryFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listAlbumCategorys(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        albums {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

**Call Query Function:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAlbumCategories = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listAlbumCategorys));
        console.log(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error:", e);
      }
    };

    fetchAlbumCategories();
  }, []);
```

**Error:**

> WARN  [WARN] 48:05.339 GraphQLAPI - ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access
> LOG  Error: [Error: No credentials]

Comment: Please write your code you're using on the front-end, write the error message in the question, share the query, and share your schema.

Comment: I share my Code

Comment: I'd do two things. Change `@connection` to `@hasMany` to have [the latest schema](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship). Secondly, I'd go to AWS AppSync, and run the query in the console to see if you can pull data.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** I would adjust your code to follow the latest `@hasMany` schema, using [this example](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship):

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

**Secondly,** you'll need to add `IAM` authentication for public users to make queries.

```
type Customer @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }])
```

The error *"ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access"* is because you have not provided a means for public users to make queries.

Lastly, to add authentication, run `amplify add auth` in the `CLI`, and walkthrough the options, until you find adding a secondary option for cognito user pools of IAM. You can test this works first in AWS AppSync before writing front-end code.

You can learn more about authorization rules [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/).

**You code could look like this:**

```
type AlbumCategory @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  albums: [Album] @hasMany
}

type Album @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  by: String!
  numberOfLikes: Int!
  imageUri: String!
  artistsHeadline: String!
  songs: [Song] @hasMany
}

type Song @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }]) {
  id: ID!
  imageUri: String!
  uri: String!
  title: String!
  artist: String!
  albumId: ID!
  album: Album @hasMany
}
```